# Maven surefire plugin default strategy to run tests

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Im using MavenSureFire plugin to run unit test , but I couldn't find what's Surefire plugin default Strategy to run test cases. Does it run parallel or sequential ? Below is my plugin configuration in pom . I've one suite class , which contains multiple SubClasses . What is the execution strategy of subclasses ?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>${runSuite}</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Note: I've configured any parallel execution so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should run in the naming order of the class (alphabetically). I assume it has nothing to do with maven but goes by the java convention of executing the class.

Comment: Is it parallel or sequential within class Methods ?

Comment: it is sequential.